# Boolean operator full-text-search

Tags: full-text-search, boolean-operations

I am writing because I need to sort Google searches by date but not using the existing manual filtering tool.
Does anyone know if there is a Boolean operator or whatever, with which it would obtain as an example, the last entries from a year to the present?

Example of searching with other Booleans:

"arcelormittal" AND invest AND filetype: pdf -quarter ...

In this case I would like to add a boolean operator to reduce the searches to this last year or to this month.

I know, as I say above, that you can do it with the date filter manually, once the search is done. Actually, what I need is to have the searches filtered by the date range specified in the search terms and not manually.
I need this because I do a lot of searches and then I automate they.

Thank you very much.